# как удалить первое вхождение определенного символа в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

как удалить первое вхождение определенного символа в строке?
например: из а1 удалить первое вхождение "2" и получить а2

```
a1 = "123123123"
a2 = "13123123"
```

Comment: https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.replace/

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода [str.replace](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.replace/):

```py
a = "123123123"

a = a.replace('2', '', 1) # 13123123
```